# How to auto-assign value to the permitted params in Rails controller create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have Ruby On Rails application. I have created method in my `CommentsController` and I want to always auto-assign value to one of the permitted fields (in my case its :commenter)"

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @meme = Meme.find(params[:meme_id])
    @comment = @meme.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to meme_path(@meme)
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
    end
end
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `auto-assign` always, or if there is a no value for the field `commenter`, then .. ?

Comment: Hi! I have updated question. Yes, I want every single time I create comment with different user, to save that user username (or whatever field to the `:commenter` )

Comment: There must be value for the field commenter (since its necessary to sign up to my app, you should have username as a required field)

Comment: Well, in that case, I know when creating comments, you of-course sending the commenter value through the comment creation form, right? If not, you should do.

Comment: Is the commenter the current Devise user ?

Comment: @chumakoff Yes, it is.

Comment: you could do then `@meme.comments.create(comment_params.merge(commenter: current_user))`.. In that case, you can remove `commenter` from the strong params declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, you should authenticate a user. Since the current user is authenticated there is no need to pass him in parameters. You can do something like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @meme = Meme.find(params[:meme_id])
    @comment = @meme.comments.create(comment_params)

    redirect_to meme_path(@meme)
  end

private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body).merge(commenter: current_user)
    end
end
```

Comment: You can skip `before_action :authenticate_user!` if current user is not required. In this case if a user is not authenticated then `commenter` will be set to nil

Answer (score 3):

Merging it along with the comment_params, you can add more params that you want as key and values in the second hash

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:body).merge!({commenter: 'default_value'})
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`tap`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/tap):

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body).tap do |comment|
    comment[:commenter] = "some value here"
    comment[:any_other_key] = "some other value"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you add `t.string :commenter, default: "default_commenter"` in your migrations. That way if you are working on the console then you won't get blank values. It will also clean up the controller code.